# jQuery hover to set position left doesn't work in IE?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-hover

I'm having an issue making the follow code work in ANY version of IE.  The div that should be showing up simply does not appear on hover at all...

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'height':'390px','width':'475px'});
    $(this).find('.preview_window').css('left', '0px');
},
function(){
    $(this).css({'height':'29px','width':'29px'});
    $(this).find('.preview_window').css('left', '-9999px');
}
);
```

It's GOT to be something really stupid... seeing as how it works on everything but IE across the board.  Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Why are you not just doing all of this in CSS? as all you are doing is changing CSS information

Comment: I was having some flickering issues when it was all set in CSS. (again, only in IE)  Even stranger than my issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out IE just didn't like where I was putting line breaks in the function...

Here is the changed code that IE can apparently understand better.

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'height':'390px','width':'475px'});
    $(this).find('.preview_window').css('left', '0px');
},function(){ //This was also on two lines before
    $(this).css({'height':'29px','width':'29px'});
    $(this).find('.preview_window').css('left', '-9999px');
}); // This was on two lines before
```

I knew it was something stupid. Everything works now. =/

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add the position attribute to that div :

```
preview_window {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: maybe you could try jquery functions hide() and show() instead of playing with position...

Comment: I actually changed it from hide/show because of a display bug in IE.  I have a google map inside the div being shown, and because it is hidden on page load, it doesn't size the map right once it is shown and the pin is not centered. (it's in top left because it thinks it's sized 0x0)  In older IE, the map doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specifically define the position method like this:

```
$('.trigger').hover(function() {
    $(this).css({'height':'390px','width':'475px'});
    $(this).find('.preview_window').css({'position':'absolute','left':'0px'});
},
function(){
    $(this).css({'height':'29px','width':'29px'});
    $(this).find('.preview_window').css({'position':'absolute','left':'-9999px'});
});
```

Comment: that styling is set in CSS.